# Avoid calling functions multiple times ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

So basically I have a function called `calculations()` that is doing some calculations and returning some objects.

The problem is that in a component, I need to call this function several times to get the objects it returns and it ends up generating a delay in the code. Like that:

```
const myTest1 = this.calculations().value1;
const myTest2 = this.calculations().value2;
const myTest3 = this.calculations().value3;

console.log(myTest1, myTest2, myTest3)
```

Is there any way to do this without having to call the function multiple times? I'm using class components so I can't use the hooks from the new version of react.

Comment: "I can't use the hooks from the new version of react." — Hooks were introduced in React 16.8 which was released on 6 February 2019. Wikipedia lists 12 releases of React since then. They're hardly new any more.

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you want to do multiple things with the result of an expression then **store the result of the expression in a variable**.

```
const myResults = this.calculations();
const myTest1 = myResults.value1;
const myTest2 = myResults.value2;
const myTest3 = myResults.value3;

console.log(myTest1, myTest2, myTest3)
```

That said, in the specific case where the "multiple things" are "store property values in variables" you could also use a destructuring operation:

```
const { value1: myTest1, value2: myTest2, value3: myTest3 } = this.calculations();
```

Answer (score 0):

If the calculcations are taking time but you need to log all the results together you may want to looking to wrapping each result in a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and returning that. This way you then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all the calculations to complete (or fail) before dealing with them.

Here's a short demonstration.

```js
// Calculation returns a promise
// In this example it waits for
// `n` seconds and then returns `n` times 10
// but the `setTimeout` can be whatever your calculation is
function calculation(n) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(n * 10), n * 1000);
  });
}

// Example array of calculations required
const calcsNeeded = [1, 2, 3];

async function doCalcs() {

  // `map` over the array and return the promise
  // for each calculation
  const promises = calcsNeeded.map(calculation);

  // Wait for them to all resolve (or be rejected)
  const results = await Promise.all(promises);

  // Log the results
  // Note that "Logged first" gets logged first
  console.log(results);
}

doCalcs();
console.log('Logged first');
```